# Problema en React con el router y dashboard

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Cuando voy al localhost:3001/login si me muestra el h1 que tengo en ese componente, pero cuando quiero ir al localhost:3001/marvel no me muestra nada (osea el h1 que tambien tengo en ese componente) y me dice la consola que no lo encuentra

Codigo 1) AppRouter.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginScreen from "../components/login/LoginScreen";
import DashboardRoutes from "./DashboardRoutes";

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<DashboardRoutes />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

    export default AppRouter;
```

Codigo 2) DashboardRoutes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import MarvelScreen from "../components/marvel/MarvelScreen";
import HeroScreen from "../components/heroes/HeroScreen";
import DcScreen from "../components/dc/DcScreen";
import { Navbar } from "../components/ui/NavBar";

const DashboardRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/marvel" element={<MarvelScreen />} />
          <Route path="/heroe/:heroeId" element={<HeroScreen />} />
          <Route path="/dc" element={<DcScreen />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/marvel" />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default DashboardRoutes;
```

Componentes como LoginScreen,MarvenScreen, etc tienen este simple formato

```
import React from 'react'

const LoginScreen = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>LoginScreen</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de `LoginScreen` y `DashboardRoutes`?

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta para que quede mas completa y pueda resolver tu duda

Comment: Tal vez no debas usar las rutas de esa manera. Si no me equivoco todas tienen que estar dentro de la misma etiqueta `Routes`. [Así](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview#nested-routes) Además necesitarás un [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) para que se carguen las rutas hijas ¿Obtienes algún error en la consola?

Comment: la idea de usar AppRouter como route padre y luego DashboadRouts como route hija, es que NavBar (que es una barra de navegacion) se aplique solo en DcScreen, MarvelScreen y que esa barra de navgacion NO se vea en Login, por eso la divicion en route
Probe colocando el Oulet en DashboardRoute y sigue sin funcionar